# Change border color of ul to siblings "a" background-color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am creating a menu with submenus nested within. Each ancor tag has a different background color.
What I would like to happen is that each nested ul's bottom border color is the same as that of the ancor tag's background color in that specific group "li".

I am half way there it seems, but now all of the nested ul's get the same border color from the first ancor tags background color. not sure where I am going wrong.

```
<nav id="nav-main">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Spa Menu</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Packages</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Touch Therapy</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Hands & Feet</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Grooming</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Specialised Treatments</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Bookings</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Packages</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Touch Therapy</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Hands & Feet</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Grooming</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Specialised Treatments</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Vouchers</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav><!-- END #nav-main -->
```

the css

```
#nav-main {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 8em;
}
#nav-main > ul > li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#nav-main > ul > li a {
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Brandon Grotesque', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
}
#nav-main > ul > li ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    border-bottom: 8px solid ;
}
#nav-main > ul > li ul li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    background: #fff;
    color: #b0b0b0;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#nav-main > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a {
    background-color: #5ac6eb;
}
#nav-main > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a {
    background-color: #bcd34d;
}
#nav-main > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a {
    background-color: #5ac6eb;
}
#nav-main > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a {
    background-color: #5ac6eb;
}
```

and the js to get it to work

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    'use strict';

    var child = $('#nav-main ul >li >ul');

    child.css({
        'border-color': child.siblings('a').css('background-color')
    });
});
```

Comment: create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @brunozrk that's not constructive and often not necessary

Comment: @Popnoodles In this case it would be helpful...

Comment: So if you're going to post an answer you would create one.

Comment: why not @Popnoodles? is better see what is happening, not just with words

Comment: @brunozrk If you were being constructive you would copy the code into jsfiddle and post the link to it.

Comment: @Popnoodles, creating a fiddle is recommended, when possible. `If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to ... then do so` http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes I agree, but creating it and posting the link as a comment, or editing the post and adding it there is constructive. Just commenting "create a fiddle" is not so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#nav-main ul > li > ul').each(function() {
   $(this).css('border-color', $(this).prev('a').css('background-color'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zneapo43/

I have to honestly say  though, it looks very messy.